# Can't Resolve setOnPlaceSelectedListener

Tags: google-places-api, resolve, searchbar

Hello all I am getting an error while trying to use googles search bar. Says can't resolve setOnPlaceSelectedListener. I am using this a library past 24 which was the only solution i could find online about this issue so now I'm kinda stuck. (compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'). I am also using this xml code which doesn't give me any errors. Any suggestions?

XML:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />
```

Fragment:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact problem and it took me soo long to resolve it. It was a very silly mistake. For me, it was because I had placed setOnPlaceSelectedListener() outside of the onCreate() method. If your problem is the same as mine, it's a very easy fix. Just copy-paste the fragment declaration and its listener into the onCreate() method. Hope that helps.